# Open a file with a specific extension, regardless of the name

Tags: python, pandas, pathlib

I have the following code:

```
folder_names = []
spreadsheet_contents = []
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
current_directory = Path.cwd()


for folder in current_directory.iterdir():
    
    folder_names.append(folder.name)
    
    file_n = '*.csv'
         
    spreadsheet_path = folder / file_n
    spreadsheet_contents.append(pd.read_excel(spreadsheet_path, skiprows = 1, header = None, usecols = [5]))
```

The problem is that the .csv files in each folder are named differently. The '*.csv' method does not work. Does anyone have an idea how to open the .csv file for each subfolder even though they are all named differently?

Comment: Go through file listing in `folder` and check files for extension. Basically put a `for` with `if` in your current loop.

Comment: call glob after changing the dir to desired dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using `pathlib` for the paths. `pathlib` supports recursive globbing using the `**` syntax (can be quite slow though):

```
files = Path('.').glob('**/*.csv')
```

For reading the files you can do something like (passing the arguments that suits your file structure):

```
pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f) for f in files)
```

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of simplicity im not writing the complete code,

```
import glob
```

replace `file_n = '*.csv'` with `file_n = glob.glob('*.csv')`

and loop over the list of file names.